# I need to call a test in class selenium C# to another class

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a class A which has some passed test cases , and another class B which depends on class A .
So i need to call a test from class A in class B to check if it passed or not to continue my test in class B.
Here is the code related to class B
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNwbT.png)
The problem that when it's run " the last run test is the test in class A " so when the compiler go to read the line "addtocart" it gave me an exception cause he couldn't find the element on the second driver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when i put the driver as a public element in class A , and call him in class B to prevent calling the driver twice .